# NP completeness of Hamiltonian cycle for the family of *dual graphs* to plane, cubic, triply connected graphs?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-complete, planar-graphs

It is well known that the Hamiltonian cycle problem is NP-complete on the family of planar, cubic and triply connected graphs: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0205049

For a problem I'm thinking about, it would be insightful to know if the Hamiltonian cycle problem was also NP-complete on the family of plane graphs whose dual is cubic and triply connected.

I would be interested in any result of the following form:

Let $D_d = \{ G \text{ a planar graph} : G^* \text{ has max degree bounded by } d \}$. Then for some $d$, Hamiltonian cycle is NP complete on $D_d$.

Comment: The degree of a vertex of G* corresponds to the number of edges in a face of G. So a simpler way of asking your question is to ask about the Hamiltonian cycle problem in planar graphs with an upper bound on the number of edges in each face. As a separate note, reducing from grid-graph Hamiltonian cycle is probably a good idea if you want to end up with each face having a small number of edges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following paper shows that the Hamiltonian cycle problem is NP-complete in **maximal** planar graphs:

> A. Wigderson
>   The Complexity of the Hamiltonian Circuit Problem for Maximal Planar Graphs
>   Technical Report #298, Department of EECS, Princeton University, February 1982.
>   https://www.math.ias.edu/avi/node/820

In a maximal planar graph, every face is a triangle; hence the dual of a  maximal planar graph is cubic. It is easy to see that the dual of a maximal planar graph is triply connected.

Therefore your problem is NP-complete.

Comment: In fact the duals of cubic 3-connected graphs are exactly the maximal planar graphs.

Comment: Your answer here and your comments on a few other questions of mine (notably this one: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41998/is-balanced-hamiltonian-cycle-np-complete-on-maximal-plane-graphs/41999#41999 )  helped me to move a research project forward. Now that it is wrapping up I would like to acknowledge your input. I would like to respect your right to keep your identity anonymous, so I am referring to you as Gamow with a link your stackexchange profile. If you would like me to acknowledge you differently or to discuss this further, please contact me at LNAJT@math.wisc.edu.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Yes, that's fine with me. It it is enough to refer to a "discussion on stackexchange" plus html.